# file_put_contents only creates file, don't write to it

Tags: php, file, file-put-contents

I have a function, which has to create a file and write to it, but it only does the first thing. File permissions are `0777`.

My code:

```
function addCookie($id) {
    $path = "users/".$id.".txt";
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $cookies = file_get_contents($path) + 1;
        file_put_contents($path, $cookies);
    } else {
        $cookies = "1";
        file_put_contents($path, $cookies);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your PHP Error log say?

Comment: Never, ever use `0777` as your permissions. Using it on shared servers means that any user can: Read, Write and Execute your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Relative paths may not work properly. Always use full paths and make sure the directory is writable.**

and

**Use PHP [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)!**

Below are these fixes:

```
/*** 
  Set error log at the top of the page:
 ***/
error_reporting(E_ALL);  

function addCookie($id) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/users/".$id.".txt";
    if(is_file($path) && is_readable($path)) {
      $cookies = (int)file_get_contents($path) + 1;
    } else {
       $cookies = "1";
    }
    file_put_contents($path, $cookies);
}
```

Personally, I think you're being overly careful with *if file exists* and can happy open the file and simply act if it fails for any reason:

```
function addCookie($id) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/users/".$id.".txt";
    $cookies = file_get_contents($path);        
    $cookies++; //will equal value + 1 or false + 1. Both work for you.
    file_put_contents($path, $cookies);
}
```